# T-SQL : Get Current + Previous years from date table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have year values from 2009 to 2015 in my date table.
I only want to get years from Min(year) to Current(year).

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks friends! all of your methods work. I just marked first answer as Answer for the sake of marking an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select thouse "smaller or equal" to current year

```
select * from table where datepart(year, date) <= datepart(year, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable
  WHERE year BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(year) FROM yourTable) AND DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

Or, if you don't have years but instead full dates:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable
  WHERE theDate BETWEEN (SELECT DATEPART(year, MIN(theDate)) FROM yourTable) AND DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest is:

```
select *
from t
where YearValue <= year(getdate())
```

The minimum value takes care of itself -- you have no data before the minimum year.